# What is the difference between making calls to mvc controller methods and WCF WEB API Rest Service Calls?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, web-services, wcf-web-api

What is the difference between making calls to mvc controller methods and WCF WEB API Rest Service Calls?

I can create an mvc controller post method that will allow me to execute any code i need.

I can also create a WCF Web API REST Service with MVC.

What is the difference between these two approaches to accessing data ?

More specifically what are the advantages of utilizing WCF in this scenario ?

Comment: I'm guessing this question will get alot of views now that MVC 4 Beta is out and they added Web.API to MVC =D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WCF Web API handles XML and JSON out of the box whereas you'll have to create your XML and JSON "by hand" (read: using the Serializers) when using MVC - this is only one of the benefits of WCF Web API over MVC.

Another one is the level of separation WCF Web API offers e.g. implementing your service logic vs. content negotiation.

Yet you can easily use IoC containers and unit test your APIs being created using WCF Web API.

WCF Web API mainly has been created to build ReSTful API's whereas MVC just allows it to create them too - thus with WCF Web API you'll feel more comfortable creating ReST APIs.

If you're planning to start a project from scratch as an Web (ReST) Api, you should start with WCF Web API.

If you're planning to start with a Website that also offers ReSTful Services, you should suggest MVC.

You should also regard [this tweet](https://twitter.com/#!/gblock/status/132305937754103809) from Glenn Block.

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish a typical REST API with either one.

Usually the issue boils down to (1) what specific features you need and (2) what technology you are more familiar with.

There are some features of WCF that are really neat and not available in MVC (like binary serializations, the ability to host without IIS, et cetera) but those are not typically requirements in a REST API.

Overall I would say:

- If you have an WCF implementation already in place and want to expose it as a REST API go for it with WCF.
- If you already have an MVC site and want to expose it as a REST API stick with MVC.

Comment: I did't upvote or downvote, but your answer boils down to "it all depends..." without providing concrete decision points, so I can see if someone doesn't find it useful, which is what -1 means.

Comment: @HectorCorrea your both points have nothing to do with the question #1 He has said Rest Web API (Why he needs binary serailization ? #2 how does it even matter what technologies he is familiar with. Finaly you just copied your bottom 2 points from Alexander which he answered 1 hour before you.